# Create a security realm in Wildfly

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

I want to secure some ejb hosted on my Widlfly AS, so I start creating my security-domain. I don't want to authenticate on ApplicationRealm so I define my security-realm and point it in my security-domain. I want to store credentials in a text file. Here is the code:

```
<security-domain name="mydomain" cache-type="default">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required"/>
    <module-option name="realm" value="myrealm"/>
    <module-option name="userProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/myrealm-users.properties"/>
    <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/myrealm-roles.properties"/>
  </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

still it look like my ejb are affected by ApplicationRealm by the "other" security-domain. Can I define a custom security realm and use it by security-domain in Wildfly? If yes how can I add users to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a file `jboss-web.xml` in `WEB-INF` to override the default `other` domain. For instance:

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/mydomain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

Then in the Wildfly config file (`standalone.xml` or the likes) you configure the `mydomain` Security Domain like you already showed. It can happily co-exist with the already present `other` domain.

There's an excellent post here: http://blog.eisele.net/2015/01/jdbc-realm-wildfly820-primefaces51.html

Comment: Hello. You're right, I think that's because EJB's inherits WEB security domain. But what if I got EJBs in a .jar?

Comment: If they are in a `.jar ` it would likely be more straightforward then if they're in an `.ear`. So I'd say just try it, likely it'll just work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add users in management realm using add-user script. By default, users generated there are stored in file.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Security+Realms provides information about how to create custom security realm.